# Why augmented_corners is not defined

Tags: python, github, chess, python-chess

I have forked code from GitHub that provided about Play online chess with real chess board.
But I found the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "board_calibration.py", line 200, in <module>
NameError: name 'augmented_corners' is not defined
[12216] Failed to execute script 'board_calibration' due to unhandled exception!
```

Here is code:

```
import cv2
import platform
from math import inf, sqrt
import pickle
from helper import rotateMatrix, perspective_transform, edge_detection
import numpy as np
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

show_info = False
cap_index = 0
cap_api = cv2.CAP_ANY
platform_name = platform.system()
for argument in sys.argv:
    if argument == "show-info":
        show_info = True
    elif argument.startswith("cap="):
        cap_index = int("".join(c for c in argument if c.isdigit()))
        if platform_name == "Darwin":
            cap_api = cv2.CAP_AVFOUNDATION
        elif platform_name == "Linux":
            cap_api = cv2.CAP_V4L2
        else:
            cap_api = cv2.CAP_DSHOW

if show_info:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo("Board Calibration",
                        'Board calibration will start. It should detect corners of the chess board almost immediately. If it does not, you should press key "q" to stop board calibration and change webcam/board position.')
    if platform_name == "Darwin":
        root.destroy()


def mark_corners(frame, augmented_corners, rotation_count):
    height, width = frame.shape[:2]
    if rotation_count == 1:
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
    elif rotation_count == 2:
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)
    elif rotation_count == 3:
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    for i in range(len(augmented_corners)):
        for j in range(len(augmented_corners[i])):
            if rotation_count == 0:
                index = str(i) + "," + str(j)
                corner = augmented_corners[i][j]
            elif rotation_count == 1:
                index = str(j) + "," + str(8 - i)
                corner = (height - augmented_corners[i][j][1], augmented_corners[i][j][0])
            elif rotation_count == 2:
                index = str(8 - i) + "," + str(8 - j)
                corner = (width - augmented_corners[i][j][0], height - augmented_corners[i][j][1])
            elif rotation_count == 3:
                index = str(8 - j) + "," + str(i)
                corner = (augmented_corners[i][j][1], width - augmented_corners[i][j][0])
            corner = (int(corner[0]), int(corner[1]))
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, index, corner, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                                0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return frame


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cap_index, cap_api)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Couldn't open your webcam. Please check your webcam connection.")
    sys.exit(0)
board_dimensions = (7, 7)

for _ in range(10):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Error reading frame. Please check your webcam connection.")
        continue

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Error reading frame. Please check your webcam connection.")
        continue
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    retval, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, patternSize=board_dimensions)
    if retval:
        if show_info:
            if platform_name == "Darwin":
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
            messagebox.showinfo("Chess Board Detected",
                                'Please check that corners of your chess board are correctly detected. The square covered by points (0,0), (0,1),(1,0) and (1,1) should be a8. You can rotate the image by pressing key "r" to adjust that. Press key "q" to save detected chess board corners and finish board calibration.')
            root.destroy()
        if corners[0][0][0] > corners[-1][0][0]:  # corners returned in reverse order
            corners = corners[::-1]
        minX, maxX, minY, maxY = inf, -inf, inf, -inf
        augmented_corners = []
        row = []
        for i in range(6):
            corner1 = corners[i]
            corner2 = corners[i + 8]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))

        for i in range(4, 7):
            corner1 = corners[i]
            corner2 = corners[i + 6]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))

        augmented_corners.append(row)

        for i in range(7):
            row = []
            corner1 = corners[i * 7]
            corner2 = corners[i * 7 + 1]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))

            for corner in corners[i * 7:(i + 1) * 7]:
                x = corner[0][0]
                y = corner[0][1]
                row.append((x, y))

            corner1 = corners[i * 7 + 6]
            corner2 = corners[i * 7 + 5]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))
            augmented_corners.append(row)

        row = []
        for i in range(6):
            corner1 = corners[42 + i]
            corner2 = corners[42 + i - 6]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))

        for i in range(4, 7):
            corner1 = corners[42 + i]
            corner2 = corners[42 + i - 8]
            x = corner1[0][0] + (corner1[0][0] - corner2[0][0])
            y = corner1[0][1] + (corner1[0][1] - corner2[0][1])
            row.append((x, y))

        augmented_corners.append(row)

        while augmented_corners[0][0][0] > augmented_corners[8][8][0] or augmented_corners[0][0][1] > \
                augmented_corners[8][8][1]:
            rotateMatrix(augmented_corners)

        pts1 = np.float32([list(augmented_corners[0][0]), list(augmented_corners[8][0]), list(augmented_corners[0][8]),
                           list(augmented_corners[8][8])])

        empty_board = perspective_transform(frame, pts1)
        edges = edge_detection(empty_board)
        # cv2.imshow("edge", edges)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
        edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)
        roi_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(edges)
        # cv2.imshow("edge", edges)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        # cv2.imshow("roi", roi_mask)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        roi_mask[:7, :] = 0
        roi_mask[:, :7] = 0
        roi_mask[-7:, :] = 0
        roi_mask[:, -7:] = 0
        # cv2.imshow("roi", roi_mask)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        # cv2.imwrite("empty_board.jpg", empty_board)

        rotation_count = 0
        while True:
            cv2.imshow('frame', mark_corners(frame.copy(), augmented_corners, rotation_count))
            response = cv2.waitKey(0)
            if response & 0xFF == ord('r'):
                rotation_count += 1
                rotation_count %= 4
            elif response & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(3) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def euclidean_distance(first, second):
    return sqrt((first[0] - second[0]) ** 2 + (first[1] - second[1]) ** 2)


first_row = euclidean_distance(augmented_corners[1][1], augmented_corners[1][7])
last_row = euclidean_distance(augmented_corners[7][1], augmented_corners[7][7])
first_column = euclidean_distance(augmented_corners[1][1], augmented_corners[7][1])
last_column = euclidean_distance(augmented_corners[1][7], augmented_corners[7][7])

if abs(first_row - last_row) >= abs(first_column - last_column):
    if first_row >= last_row:
        side_view_compensation = (1, 0)
    else:
        side_view_compensation = (-1, 0)
else:
    if first_column >= last_column:
        side_view_compensation = (0, -1)
    else:
        side_view_compensation = (0, 1)

print("Side view compensation" + str(side_view_compensation))
print("Rotation count " + str(rotation_count))
filename = 'constants.bin'
outfile = open(filename, 'wb')
pickle.dump([augmented_corners, side_view_compensation, rotation_count, roi_mask], outfile)
outfile.close()
```

This is GitHub repository: https://github.com/karayaman/Play-online-chess-with-real-chess-board/blob/main/board_calibration.py

I try to ask ChatGPT but not help me to solve this problem.

Comment: _But I found the error below:_ I don't see an error...

Comment: Move `augmented_corners = []` outside of `if-else` block.

Comment: When the `if retval:` condition is false, the assignment `augmented_corners = []` does not occur and thus it is an undefined variable.